# About different writing systems for numerals

Tags: resource-request, writing-system

The numerals used in English and other languages using a Latin alphabet are known as Arabic numerals (or, more precisely, Western Arabic numerals).
I wish to transcribe *60* (and not *sixty*) into different numeral systems.

Is there an online resource that transcribes Western Arabic numerals into other numeral systems?

Comment: I think you should specify which [numeral systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems) you are interested in.

Comment: Any numeral system based on other figures than 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Comment: I see you have received a helpful answer, so this may not matter to you. But in the future, please try to focus your questions a lot more than this. Asking for "resources for other numeral systems" is *incredibly broad*. It's also not really related to language learning, per se.  In future, please specify which numeral system, for instance, you're interested in.

Comment: You might ask a question like this on Math SE. If you're trying to express numerals in different "bases," this is fundmentally a math question, not a language question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most converters I have found support only two or three systems, for example:

- [Roman Numerals Converter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ee.arws_apps.convertvs) (Arabic to Roman & Roman to Arabic; Android app).
- calculateme: [Convert Arabic to Roman Numerals](http://www.calculateme.com/cRomanNumerals/ArabicNumeralsToRoman.htm) (web-based).
- [Hindu-Arabic numerals to Roman numerals (and vice versa)](http://www.numberconverter.net/get-math/numeral-system-converter/from-hindu-arabic-numerals-to-roman-numerals/) (web-based); see also [Numeral system converter](http://www.numberconverter.net/get-math/numeral-system-converter/) on the same site.
- [Abjad Calculator](http://www.bluelightdev.com/adib/abjadcalc.php) (web-based).
- [Chinese Number Tool](https://toshuo.com/chinese-tools/chinese-number-tool/) (Chinese to Arabic; web-based).
- [Chinese Number Converter](http://jalu.ch/coding/chinese_numbers.php) (Chinese to Arabic; web-based).
- [Roman to Arabic Numerals Converter](http://coolconversion.com/math/roman-to-arabic/) (web-based).

I have not yet found converters for

- [Thai numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_numerals),
- [Mongolian numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_numerals),
- [Devanagari numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numerals#Devanagari_numerals_and_their_Hindi_names) (or [Hindi numerals](http://blogs.transparent.com/hindi/hindi-numerals/)) ,
- [Maya numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_numerals) (a search for installable software that converts Maya numerals will result in a number of hits, but when you read the descriptions of the software programs, nothing is said about Maya numerals),
- etc., etc.

There are also numerous sites where you can download programs that you can install locally, and numerous source code repositories with source code for converters, e.g. [romanize](https://github.com/andybluntish/romanize) (JavaScript code for conversion between Arabic and Roman numerals) and [NumeralConverter](https://github.com/Walkman100/NumeralConverter) (Visual Basic and Python code for conversion between Arabic and Roman numerals).

There have also been StackOverflow question about how to code converters for numeral systems, e.g. [Convert number to string using Hebrew letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675226/convert-number-to-string-using-hebrew-letters) (C#).

Comment: Tks a lot for your answer ! Pity there is not a global converter for many numeral systems...

Comment: @XavierLabouze I'm sure that kind of thing can be programmed, but I don't have time for it at the moment.